# Searching for a WPF GIS Map

Tags: c#, wpf, postgresql, gis

I am searing for a control that I can use in wpf to actually show a GIS map.

I have all the map and layer data inside a `postgresql` database so I just need a control to actually show the data.

I looked at `SharpMap` because it had `postgresql` integretion, but there is no WPF control for that. And the version 2.0 has a WPF control but it doesn't get worked on anymore. (Last commit Jan 10, 2012)

Does somebody knows a good alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the (free) bing maps control https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh750210.aspx

Or if you are willing to part with some money Telerik do a map as part of their control suite http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/map.aspx

Comment: The problem with the bing map is that it takes the map from the internet but when the application is running there is a change you have no internet. That's why I have the map layer inside the database.

Comment: And it is actually only for one country also :)

Comment: I can't comment on the bing maps control but the telerik one has the capacity to use a custom tile provider which mean you can have the images pre downloaded for a given area and use those. I have done this before giving tiles down to a set zoom level, if they go beyond that it would download them from the internet (if possible) and add it to the local copy for next time.

Comment: Just looked and the bing control offers a similar tile source override so you should be able to do that with the free bing control

Comment: Also the devexpress control has a map like telerik. (Just to add)